# Older SciFi Movie: Marooned rocket crew battles hostile humanoid natives

Tags: story-identification, movie

Black and white film:

Rocket ship leaves earth for outer space and crash lands on planet. The crew is now marooned. The indigenous humanoids are hostile. They looked like cavemen: scraggly hair, bushy eyebrows kind of thing, and wore bearskin kind of clothes. They wielded stone knives. Nothing odd about their appearance other than that they were throwbacks. The spaceship crew did not need to wear their suits because there was an Earth-like atmosphere. Last scene features battle between ship captain and leader of humanoids. Captain defeats leader. Epilogue suggests a new world will now be created.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.

Comment: @amflare oops looks like we had the same comment :/

Comment: Did the humanoids look like humans? Have funny ears? Hair? Horns? Did they fight with laser guns? Ballistic weapons? Spears? Psychic powers? Were the Earthlings stuck in their space suits or was it a friendly atmosphere?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Good questions all… The humanoids looked like cavemen scraggly hair bushy eyebrows kind of thing and war bare skin kind of clothes nothing odd about the reparents other than they were throwbacks the spaceship crew did not need to wear their suits there it was a earth like atmosphere and the weapons were The weapons were stone knives

Answer (score 3):

Could it be *[Rocketship X-M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketship_X-M)*?

> Four men and a woman blast into outer space from the White Sands Proving Ground aboard the RX-M (Rocketship Expedition-Moon) on humanity's first expedition to Luna. Halfway there, after surviving their jettisoned and runaway first stage and a meteoroid storm, their engines suddenly quit. Recalculating fuel ratios and swapping fuel tank positions fixes the problem. After the engines fire, RX-M rapidly careens out of control on a rapid heading beyond the Moon; lowered oxygen pressure also causes the crew to slowly pass out. They gradually revive much later and discover that they have traveled some 50,000,000 miles and are now on a direct heading toward Mars. Quick calculations reveal that RX-M is only 50,000 miles away. Dr. Karl Eckstrom (John Emery) is forced to "pause and observe respectfully while something infinitely greater assumes control".

....

> Finding cave refuge, the scientists notice in the distance the primitive descendants of that civilization emerging from behind boulders and creeping toward them. Amazed, Dr. Eckstrom comments "From Atomic Age to Stone Age". Soon after leaving, two of the explorers encounter a dark-haired woman who has lost her footing and rolled down a hill toward them; she is blind, with thick, milky cataracts on both eyes. She screams upon hearing their oxygen mask-distorted voices. The radiation burned tribesmen attack, throwing large rocks and stone axes. Armed with only a revolver and a bolt-action rifle, the explorers defend themselves, purposely missing the primitives. Dr. Eckstrom is killed by a stone axe; navigator Chamberlain (Hugh O'Brian) is badly injured by a large thrown rock. The survivors finally make their way back to the RX-M.

### Trailer